# How do I make vim-latex compile correctly without having to save?

Tags: vim, latex

I just started using `Vim-LaTeX`.

The default `dvi` output didn't work for me, so I changed the default to `pdf` by adding `"let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat = 'pdf'"` to my `tex.vim`.

The only problem is that I need to save my document first (`:w`) before compiling it (`\ll`) and viewing in in Evince (`\lv`). If I do not save it, and run `\ll` and `\lv`, latex is run on the saved file before I started editing it, and not on the buffer containing my edited file.

How do I make it so that vim saves my file and compiles my document when I hit `\ll`? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

this is not the perfect solution but it will work, 
define a new map in your .vimrc:

```
map <f2> :w<cr><leader>ll
```

this works but there should exist a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: Great! This works. Perhaps there is a cleaner way of doing this... or maybe my Latex is misconfigured on my system. But this solve my problem! Thanks!

Comment: this makes vim compile in the insert mode and then returns the cursor back where it was just before hitting <f2>: imap <f2> <Esc>:w<cr><leader>ll<C-O>a

Answer (score 2):

This does specifically what you asked.  Add the following to your `.vimrc` or equivalent:

```
autocmd FileType tex call Tex_MakeMap("<Leader>ll", ":w <CR> <Plug>Tex_Compile", 'n', '<buffer>')
autocmd FileType tex call Tex_MakeMap("<Leader>ll", "<ESC> :w <CR> <Plug>Tex_Compile", 'v', '<buffer>')
```

Answer (score 1):

I have since moved on from latex suite and i am now using latexmk which works really well.

Answer (score 1):

[@dc46and2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2865056/dc46and2) Your command should be:

```
autocmd FileType tex call Tex_MakeMap('<leader>ll', ':update!<CR>:call Tex_RunLaTeX()<CR>', 'n', '<buffer>')
autocmd FileType tex call Tex_MakeMap('<leader>ll', '<ESC>:update!<CR>:call Tex_RunLaTeX()<CR>', 'v', '<buffer>')
```

AFAIK, `"` are used for comments in vim.

Comment: `"` also seems to be used for strings (http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:-

```
:w | !pdflatex "filename"
```

I believe this will work fine in your case.